# WebView (with iframe inside) doesn't resize back when softkeyboard disappears

Tags: android, iframe, webview

I have a `WebView`, and load iframe in `loadData`. When a softkeyboard appears - the `Webview` change height, but when the softkeyboard disappears - the height of the `WebView` doesn't change. How to change height of the WebView back to fullscreen?

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbv);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String html = "<html><body><iframe src=\"https://api.motion.ai/webchat/85714?color=EFB426&sendBtn=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&inputBox=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%2F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&token=9b32ca23536d9816b448d2e4c53434dc\" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(html,"text/html","UTF-8");

}
```

}

xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.hr_bot.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wbv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

So, Now i have something like this:

```
final EKRAN myEkran = new EKRAN(MainActivity.this);
        MAIN  =   findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

        MAIN.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                MAIN.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int screenHeight = MAIN.getRootView().getHeight();
                int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

                Log.d( String.valueOf(1) , "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

                if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.10) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
                    // keyboard is opened
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this , "COOL1 " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = webView.getLayoutParams();
                    params1.width = myEkran.W(100); // IN %
                    params1.height = myEkran.H(45); // IN %
                    webView.setLayoutParams(params1);
                    webView.requestLayout();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this , "COOL2 " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // keyboard is closed

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = webView.getLayoutParams();
                    params1.width = myEkran.W(100); // IN %
                    params1.height = myEkran.H(92); // IN %
                    webView.setLayoutParams(params1);
                    webView.requestLayout();
                }
            }
        });


         webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbv);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String html = "<html><body><iframe src=\"https://api.motion.ai/webchat/85714?color=EFB426&sendBtn=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&inputBox=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%2F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82&token=9b32ca23536d9816b448d2e4c53434dc\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe></body></html>";
        webView.loadData(html,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: @NikolaLukic I think its a WebView, because I set custom background color  to it and after deformation bg was white

Comment: Try like this : YOUR_CONTROL.getLayoutParams().height =   Intro runOnUiThread make sure also on html content .

Comment: Important : You need to use FrameLayout ( only support custom positions - absolute ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Detect keyboard isHihhen or visible :***

```
// MAIN is root view see in design window (also enter id for root view ):

View MAIN;

...

    //########################
    // Put this intro OnCreate 
    //########################

    MAIN =   findViewById(R.id.main);

    MAIN.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Rect r = new Rect();
            MAIN.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight = MAIN.getRootView().getHeight();
            int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

            Log.d( String.valueOf(1) , "keypadHeight = " + keypadHeight);

            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) { // 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
                // keyboard is opened
                Toast.makeText( context_pass , "COOL1 " , 1);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText( context_pass , "COOL2 " , 1);
                // keyboard is closed
            }
        }
    });
```

**If your webview is deformed use this code after keyboard hides:**

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = YOUR_CONTROL.getLayoutParams();
                    params1.width = MY_EKRAN.W(100); // IN %
                    params1.height = MY_EKRAN.H(100); // IN %
                    YOUR_CONTROL.setLayoutParams(params1);


 OR


  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

              // runs on UI thread
              YOUR_CONTROL.getLayoutParams().height = ( MY_EKRAN.HEIGHT()/100*10);

                }
            });
```

***DEF :***

```
//global
  EKRAN MY_EKRAN;

 // in onCreate
  MY_EKRAN = new EKRAN( context_pass );
```

***Class for diametric dimensions and positions (add like new file - new java class) :***

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
/**
 * Created by nikola on 10/17/16.
 */
//##############################################
// SCREEN - EKRAN CLASS
//##############################################
public class EKRAN {

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    Point size_ = new Point();
    static int width;
    static int height;

    EKRAN(Context CONTEXT_) {

        dm = CONTEXT_.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
        height = dm.heightPixels;
        width = dm.widthPixels;

    }

    public static int WIDTH() {

        return width;

    }
    public static int HEIGHT(){

        return height;

    }
    public int W( int PER_ ){

        return width/100*PER_;

    }
    public int H( int PER_   ){


        return height/100*PER_;

    }

    //////////////////
    //extras
    /////////////////
    public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP ( float DP_VALUE )
    {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DP_VALUE , dm );
    }

    public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP2 ( float DP_VALUE )
    {
        float res = DP_VALUE * ( dm.ydpi / 160f);
        return  (int) res;
    }



}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if u also tell me how to detect when soft keyboard hides. I've tried different solutions, but didn't find any working

Comment: It makes webview fullscreen, but not resizable. So, now i'm trying to set layoutparams twice in `onGlobalLayout()` (When keyboard is open, i set params1.height to 45, and when keyboard is closed, i set params1.height to 100), the problem is WebView doesn't want to change height to 100 again. I tried to use `webView.requestLayout();` after `webView.setLayoutParams(params1);` but it doesnt' help. I've updated my code in the post.

Comment: It didn't help.